# How do I use ffmpeg to convert audible files

Tags: macos, open-source

I'm running ffmpeg v2.8.1 from Homebrew, and trying to convert [Audible](https://www.audible.com) files but there's some trick I"m missing.

This command produces this error output.

```
ffmpeg -activation_bytes 1CEB00DA -i Volume1.aax -vn -c:a copy output.mp4

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc9a4010600] [aax] file checksum == d72f1f04e3c73d0bc68e742db1bc69b58dc3a500
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc9a4010600] [aax] mismatch in checksums!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc9a4010600] error reading header
Volume1.aax: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I know the file is ok, because it plays in iTunes. I does have the file image/cover art embedded in it as well,

From the ffmpeg docs, I read
[Audible AAX files are encrypted M4B files](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Audible-AAX), and they can be decrypted by specifying a 4 byte activation secret.

I'm presuming - probably incorrectly - that the one given is ok. If not, how does one find that secret.

Comment: See also https://github.com/KrumpetPirate/AAXtoMP3

Comment: Get your activation bytes online: https://audible-converter.ml/

Answer (score 49):

First run these commands:

```
brew install chromedriver ffmpeg
sudo easy_install pip
pip install selenium requests
git clone https://github.com/inAudible-NG/audible-activator
cd audible-activator
sed -i '' 's,chromedriver_path = "./chromedriver",chromedriver_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver",' audible-activator.py
./audible-activator.py
```

Then enter your Audible username and password and wait for a while for the eight character activation key to be printed.

If you do not run the `sed` command that changes the value of the `chromedriver_path` variable, `./audible-activator.py` results in an error like `'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH` even if `chromedriver` is on the path or in the `audible-activator` directory. If your `sed` is GNU `sed`, replace `sed -i ''` with `sed -i`.

After that run a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -activation_bytes youractivationkey -i input.aax -c copy output.m4b
```

(I edited the command above based on the comments by LiWang and marcus erronius to replace `output.m4a;mv output.m4{a,b}` with `output.m4b` and to replace `-vn -c:v copy` with `-c copy`.)

If you try to use the `ffmpeg` command above with an `aa` file instead of an `aax` file, it results in an error like `Option activation_bytes not found`. To download a book from Audible as `aax` instead of `aa`, choose "Enhanced" from the "Audio Quality" dropdown in the view for downloading a book.

`aax` files are encrypted `mp4` / `m4a` / `m4b` files so the `ffmpeg` command above does not re-encode audio and it preserves metadata such as chapters. `mp4`, `m4a`, and `m4b` are alternative filename extensions for the MPEG-4 Part 14 container format. The `m4a` and `m4b` extensions were originally introduced by Apple. One difference between the `m4a` and `m4b` extensions is that the option to remember the previous playback position in iTunes is enabled by default for files with an `m4b` extension but not for files with an `m4a` extension. iTunes also displays files with an `m4b` extension under audiobooks by default.

Old versions of iTunes did not have the checkbox to enable remembering the previous playback position, but remembering the previous playback position was always enabled for files with an `m4b` extension, so even Wikipedia still incorrectly states that "an `.m4a` audio file cannot "bookmark" (remember the last listening spot), whereas `.m4b` extension files can." (Even though I don't know if there are still other media players which behave like old versions of iTunes in that respect.)

The UTI for the `m4b` extension is `com.apple.protected-mpeg-4-audio` and Finder shows the kind of all `m4b` files as "protected MPEG-4 audio" even though all files with an `m4b` extension do not have copy protection.

Comment: I'm using `.aax` files and getting the error: `Unrecognized option 'activation_bytes'.`. Any ideas? Has Audible changed their format in the last year?

Comment: Any reason to convert to `*.m4a` and then rename as `*.m4b`? Why not just do: `ffmpeg -activation_bytes youractivationkey -i input.aax -vn -c:a copy output.m4b`?

Comment: @LiWang It resulted in an error with older versions of ffmpeg, but that no longer seems to be the case.

Comment: @user4669748 I see. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: I had to use this command to get python working, but after this went perfect!
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2

Comment: Note: if you want the album art (book cover) to be copied to the resulting file, replace `-vn` with `-c:v copy`. ffmpeg sees the cover art as a video track, and it won't appreciably increase the size of the file.

Comment: This answer does not work anymore...  It should be updated for 2020.

Comment: Worked for me in 2021! Since the introduction of Book.app I prefer the `.m4a` format which can be opened in iTunes (unlike `.m4b` which takes you to Book)

Comment: The process fails at the authentication step as Chrome first showed an INVALID_CERT error, then after I've allowed insecure certs in the chrome webdriver options, the window won't even be shown anymore. Trying to access the German portals.

Comment: Therefore, I used Firefox with the following command line (`geckodriver` must additionally be installed eg via `brew`): `./audible-activator.py --username <username> --password <password> --firefox -l de`

Answer (score 10):

This will get you your activation secret:

https://github.com/inAudible-NG/audible-activator

Comment: I used [this script](https://github.com/KrumpetPirate/AAXtoMP3) to do the actual conversion.  It's also worth noting that you have to install `selenium` and `requests` via `pip` or `easy_install` and also download and extract chromedriver into the `audible-activator` directory for it to work.  This info is provided in `audible-activator`'s README but it is useful to know up front :)

Comment: Thanks, @intuited; that script is gold. Needed light tweaking to use GNU grep (the `ggrep` installed with `brew install grep`) on macos, but did a great job after that.

Answer (score 6):

I tried user4669748's answer, and ran into a few things worth noting, and discovered a fix that got things to work for me:

1. audible-activator.py requires Python 2.7; it fails with Python 3.
2. After starting it, the Chrome window pops-up on the screen and you start to see GUI activity, and a successful login to Audible.
3. Soon after login, browser activity seems to hang, with `Waiting for px.owneriq.net` constantly displayed in the bottom status bar.
4. After 5 minutes, I had a TimeoutException:

   ```
   [*] Player ID is 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./audible-activator.py", line 151, in <module>
       fetch_activation_bytes(username, password, options)
     File "./audible-activator.py", line 74, in fetch_activation_bytes
       search_box.submit()
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 88, in submit
       self._execute(Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: cannot determine loading status
   from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.222
     (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.98)
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
   ```

At this, I was stuck.  However, thinking that `px.owneriq.net` is some kind of ad or tracking site, I tried to "temporarily disable" it by adding to `/etc/hosts` with an invalid IP address, e.g.

```
0.0.0.0 px.owneriq.net
```

(This was a tactic suggested by a friend to stop ads in browser.)

After this addition to `/etc/hosts`, re-run the program.  It ran to completion in 30 seconds.

A 4-byte activation key was printed to the screen, and worked perfectly with ffmpeg as described in user4669748's answer.

I then restored `/etc/hosts` to its original content.